# How to configure Calendar Rule in Dynamics CRM v9.0?

Tags: calendar, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365-v9

I wanted to know that how we can configure the Calendar Rule in Dynamics CRM v9.0?

I have added one Business Closure and I am getting that record in the collection of "Calendar Rule" in C# code. But with that record I am also getting one rule of "Christmas Day" and not able to find out the same in CRM.

It would be great help if anyone help me to view the calendar rule in Dynamics CRM.

Answer (score 0):

Calendar rule can contains data from different areas:

1. Business Closure under Business Management
2. Holiday Schedule records from Service Management - Service Terms

Take a look at these places, you may find an entry of Christmas from Holiday schedule.